# Does a combination >= OR <= trigger a full table scan?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql innodb as follows:

```
messageIdStart | messageIdEnd | blob 
------------------------------------
      40             50         ...
      51             58         ...
      59             70         ...

                ...
```

I want to get all rows that have ids greater than a particular value.

For example, I want all rows that have messages with IDs greater than 55. I would do:

```
select * from table 
    where messageIdStart >= 55 or messageIdEnd <= 55;
```

This would give me the last two rows in the example data, which is fine.

Does this type of query require a full table scan? Is it going to scale poorly? There is an index on both of those columns.

If I had one row per message, I could simply do:

```
select * from table where messageId >= 55;
```

but this is what I inherited.

I'm thinking about trying to reformat the dataset into that second format, but don't want to optimize prematurely.

Thanks

Comment: "There is an index on both of those columns." Does it mean that there is a composite index on both the columns, or there is one index per columns, i.e. 2 indexes?

Comment: There is one index per column (not a composite index). I could create a composite index.

Comment: If that is the case, then your query will not use table scan, you can verify more with explain command too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have is likely to look at an index that you already have. You should confirm that that's the case by using EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN EXTENDED.

```
explain select * from table 
where messageIdStart >= 55 or messageIdEnd <= 55;
```

If you see that the query is resulting in selection of your index, you aren't doing table scan. I hypothesize that MySQL will use index.

You also have the ability to provide [hints to the query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) like so:

```
select * from table use index (idx_table_messageIdStart)
where messageIdStart >= 55 or messageIdEnd <= 55;
```

On a small table, the database engine may recognize appropriate indexes and still may do table scan if it believes that table scan will be faster ([Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25105a/2))

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the attribute on which you are performing the '>=' or '<=' operation. If there is a [tree based index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Index_implementations) available for that attribute, then the entire table scan is not required. You can simply prune out the subtrees that fall off the range.

If there is any other type of index or if there is no index on that attribute, you will have to perform a full table scan.